# Incremental addition with condition in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like this :

```
finalSondDF.show()
    +---------------+------------+----------------+
    |webService_Name|responseTime|numberOfSameTime|
    +---------------+------------+----------------+
    |    webservice1|          80|               1|
    |    webservice1|          87|               2|
    |    webservice1|         283|               1|
    |    webservice2|          77|               2|
    |    webservice2|          80|               1|
    |    webservice2|          81|               1|
    |    webservice3|          63|               3|
    |    webservice3|         145|               1|
    |    webservice4|         167|               1|
    |    webservice4|         367|               2|
    |    webservice4|         500|               1|
    +---------------+------------+----------------+
```

and I want to get a result like this :

```
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
|webService_Name|responseTime|numberOfSameTime|Result|
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
|    webservice1|          80|               1|     1|
|    webservice1|          87|               2|     3|  ==> 2+1
|    webservice1|         283|               1|     4|  ==> 1+2+1
|    webservice2|          77|               2|     2|  
|    webservice2|          80|               1|     3|  ==> 2+1
|    webservice2|          81|               1|     4|  ==> 2+1+1
|    webservice3|          63|               3|     3|
|    webservice3|         145|               1|     4|  ==> 3+1
|    webservice4|         167|               1|     1|
|    webservice4|         367|               2|     3|  ==> 1+2
|    webservice4|         500|               1|     4|  ==> 1+2+1
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
```

here the **result** is the sum of `numberOfSameTime` inferior of the current `responseTime`
I can't find a logic to do that. Can any one help me !!

Comment: cumulative sum is the solution . Use window function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If your data is in increasing order with `responseTime` column* for each group of `webService_Name` column then you can benefit from *cumulative sum* using `Window` function as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("webService_Name").orderBy("responseTime")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("Result", sum("numberOfSameTime").over(windowSpec)).show(false)
```

and you should have

```
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
|webService_Name|responseTime|numberOfSameTime|Result|
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
|webservice1    |80          |1               |1     |
|webservice1    |87          |2               |3     |
|webservice1    |283         |1               |4     |
|webservice2    |80          |1               |3     |
|webservice2    |81          |1               |4     |
|webservice2    |77          |2               |2     |
|webservice3    |145         |1               |4     |
|webservice3    |63          |3               |3     |
|webservice4    |167         |1               |1     |
|webservice4    |367         |2               |3     |
|webservice4    |500         |1               |4     |
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
```

**Note that the `responseTime` as to be *number type* and in *increasing order* for each `webService_Name` for the above case to work**

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm

Comment: great to hear that @jean-marc Thanks for the upvote and acceptance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Window` function available in spark and calculate the `cumulative` `sum` as below.

```
  //dummy data 
  val d1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
    ("webservice1", 80, 1),
    ("webservice1", 87, 2),
    ("webservice1", 283, 1),
    ("webservice2", 77, 2),
    ("webservice2", 80, 1),
    ("webservice2", 81, 1),
    ("webservice3", 63, 3),
    ("webservice3", 145, 1),
    ("webservice4", 167, 1),
    ("webservice4", 367, 2),
    ("webservice4", 500, 1)
  )).toDF("webService_Name","responseTime","numberOfSameTime")

  //window functionn 
  val window = Window.partitionBy("webService_Name").orderBy($"webService_Name")
    .rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)

  // create new column for Result
  d1.withColumn("Result", sum("numberOfSameTime").over(window)).show(false)
```

Output:

```
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
|webService_Name|responseTime|numberOfSameTime|Result|
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
|webservice4    |167         |1               |1     |
|webservice4    |367         |2               |3     |
|webservice4    |500         |1               |4     |
|webservice2    |77          |2               |2     |
|webservice2    |80          |1               |3     |
|webservice2    |81          |1               |4     |
|webservice3    |63          |3               |3     |
|webservice3    |145         |1               |4     |
|webservice1    |80          |1               |1     |
|webservice1    |87          |2               |3     |
|webservice1    |283         |1               |4     |
+---------------+------------+----------------+------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are ordering with sebService_Name and I doubt it will generate the same result as the OP wants.